# Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have two lists, `l1` and `l2`.  I want to perform `l1 - l2`, which returns all elements of `l1` not in `l2`.

I can think of a naive loop approach to doing this, but that is going to be really inefficient.  What is a pythonic and efficient way of doing this?

As an example, if I have `l1 = [1,2,6,8] and l2 = [2,3,5,8]`, `l1 - l2` should return `[1,6]`

Comment: Just a tip: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) states that lowercase "L" should not be used because it looks too much like a 1.

Comment: I agree.  I read this whole question and the answers wondering why people kept using eleven and twelve.  It was only when I read @spelchekr 's comment that it made sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping rows from dataframe based on a "not in" condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition)

Comment: @JimG. Dataframe and list is not the same thing.

Comment: This question is not well defined. Lists allow duplicate items. Should [1, 1, 2, 3] - [1, 2] return [1, 3] or just [3]? The solutions below all seem to to assume that it should return [3], that all members which match an element of the second list should be removed from the first list. You sometimes need list operations to obey algebraic properties. If A - B = C, then C + B = A. That isn't the case here, since duplicate values are lost.

Comment: See also: [How to find list intersection?](/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection). (This question is for list *difference*, which is equivalent to removing the intersection from the first input.)

Comment: @spelchekr Not true. PEP 8 is against it *"as single character variable names"*. Not as part of a longer variable name.

Answer (score 780):

Python has a language feature called [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that is perfectly suited to making this sort of thing extremely easy. The following statement does exactly what you want and stores the result in `l3`:

```
l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
```

`l3` will contain `[1, 6]`.

Comment: Very pythonic; I like it!  How efficient is it?

Comment: I believe quite efficient, and it has the benefit of being extremely readable and clear as to what you're trying to accomplish. I came across a blog post you might find interesting relating to efficiency: http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/

Comment: @fandom: the list comprehension itself is quite efficient (although a generator comprehension might be more efficient by not duplicating elements in memory), but the `in` operator isn't that efficient on a list.  `in` on a list is O(n), whereas `in` on a set is O(1).  However, until you get to thousands of elements or more, you're unlikely to notice the difference.

Comment: `l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in set(l2)]` ? I am sure if `set(l2)` would be called more than once.

Comment: @Danosaure: yes, `set(l2)` would be called for each element of `l1`. In general, if you're going to be using `in` a lot, you probably shouldn't be using a list (or tuple) to begin with (though if you know it'll always be really small it wouldn't be terrible).

Comment: for LARGE lists where one wants the `O(1)`ness of sets but doesn't want to call `set` again and again, one can use `[x for l2s in [set(l2)] for x in l1 if x not in l2s]`

Comment: You could also just set `l2s = set(l2)` and then say `l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2s]`. Slightly easier.

Comment: If you are able to use `set` at all, you should just use [Arkku's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/130427). It's both more efficient and readable. I couldn't use sets in my application because my items aren't hashable.

Comment: FYI, in `l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in set(l2)]` ... the `set(l2)` part is only run once, so this should be the most efficient, readable answer that doesn't remove duplicates or reorder the list.

Comment: @EricLindauer: if you replace `x not in set(l2)` with `print(x)`, you'll see every element of `l1` printed to stdout, i.e. the `print` function will be called on every iteration. Same holds for `set(l2)`.

Comment: this would behave weird for l1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] and l2 = [2, 3, 3]. It would return [1]. And we would probably expect [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Beware the list size! This solution becomes very expensive for large lists. It scales way worse than subtracting two sets.

Answer (score 248):

One way is to use sets:

```
>>> set([1,2,6,8]) - set([2,3,5,8])
set([1, 6])
```

Note, however, that sets do not preserve the order of elements, and cause any duplicated elements to be removed. The elements also need to be hashable. If these restrictions are tolerable, this may often be the simplest and highest performance option.

Comment: This will also remove duplicates from `l1`, which may be an undesired side effect.

Comment: ..and lose element order (if order is important).

Comment: I just want to add that I timed this vs. the accepted answer and it was more performant by a factor of about 3: `timeit.timeit('a = [1,2,3,4]; b = [1,3]; c = [i for i in a if a not in b]', number=100000) -> 0.12061533199999985` `timeit.timeit('a = {1,2,3,4}; b = {1,3}; c = a - b', number=100000) -> 0.04106225999998969`. So if performance is a significant factor, this answer may be more appropriate (and also if you don't care about duplicates or order)

Comment: Faster but not in existing order

Comment: While it resolves my issue, question does state `returns all elements of l1 not in l2.` Hence, this does not resolve the OP issue.

Answer (score 185):

### Performance Comparisons

Comparing the performance of all the answers mentioned here on *Python 3.9.1* and *Python 2.7.16*.

#### *Python 3.9.1*

Answers are mentioned in order of performance:

1. *[Arkku's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/2063361) **`set` difference using subtraction** "-" operation - (91.3 nsec per loop)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = set([1,2,6,8]); l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "l1 - l2"
   5000000 loops, best of 5: 91.3 nsec per loop
   ```
2. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **using `set().difference()`**- (133 nsec per loop)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = set([1,2,6,8]); l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "l1.difference(l2)"
   2000000 loops, best of 5: 133 nsec per loop
   ```
3. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **list comprehension with `set` based lookup**- (366 nsec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "[x for x in l1 if x not in l2]"
    1000000 loops, best of 5: 366 nsec per loop
   ```
4. *[Donut's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211228/2063361) **list comprehension on plain list** - (489 nsec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = [2,3,5,8];" "[x for x in l1 if x not in l2]"
    500000 loops, best of 5: 489 nsec per loop
   ```
5. *[Daniel Pryden's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211325/2063361) **generator expression with `set` based lookup*** and type-casting to `list` - *(583 nsec per loop)* : Explicitly type-casting to list to get the final object as `list`, as requested by OP. If *generator expression* is replaced with *list comprehension*, it'll become same as *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) list comprehension with `set` based lookup.*

   ```
    mquadri$ mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "list(x for x in l1 if x not in l2)"
    500000 loops, best of 5: 583 nsec per loop
   ```
6. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **using `filter()`*** and explicitly type-casting to `list` (need to explicitly type-cast as in Python 3.x, it returns iterator) - *(681 nsec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "list(filter(lambda x: x not in l2, l1))"
    500000 loops, best of 5: 681 nsec per loop
   ```
7. *[Akshay Hazari's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33491327/2063361) **using combination of `functools.reduce` + `filter`** -(3.36 usec per loop)* : Explicitly type-casting to `list` as from Python 3.x it started returned returning iterator. Also we need to import `functools` to use `reduce` in Python 3.x

   ```
    mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "from functools import reduce; l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = [2,3,5,8];" "list(reduce(lambda x,y : filter(lambda z: z!=y,x) ,l1,l2))"
    100000 loops, best of 5: 3.36 usec per loop
   ```

#### *Python 2.7.16*

Answers are mentioned in order of performance:

1. *[Arkku's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/2063361) **`set` difference using subtraction** "-" operation - (0.0783 usec per loop)*

   ```
   mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = set([1,2,6,8]); l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "l1 - l2"
   10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0783 usec per loop
   ```
2. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **using `set().difference()`**- (0.117 usec per loop)*

   ```
   mquadri$ mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = set([1,2,6,8]); l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "l1.difference(l2)"
   10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.117 usec per loop
   ```
3. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **list comprehension with `set` based lookup**- (0.246 usec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "[x for x in l1 if x not in l2]"
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.246 usec per loop
   ```
4. *[Donut's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211228/2063361) **list comprehension on plain list** - (0.372 usec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = [2,3,5,8];" "[x for x in l1 if x not in l2]"
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.372 usec per loop
   ```
5. *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) **using `filter()`** - (0.593 usec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "filter(lambda x: x not in l2, l1)"
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.593 usec per loop
   ```
6. *[Daniel Pryden's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211325/2063361) **generator expression with `set` based lookup*** and type-casting to `list` - *(0.964 per loop)* : Explicitly type-casting to list to get the final object as `list`, as requested by OP. If *generator expression* is replaced with *list comprehension*, it'll become same as *[Moinuddin Quadri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868213/2063361) list comprehension with `set` based lookup.*

   ```
    mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "list(x for x in l1 if x not in l2)"
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.964 usec per loop
   ```
7. *[Akshay Hazari's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33491327/2063361) **using combination of `functools.reduce` + `filter`** -(2.78 usec per loop)*

   ```
    mquadri$ python -m timeit "l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = [2,3,5,8];" "reduce(lambda x,y : filter(lambda z: z!=y,x) ,l1,l2)"
    100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 usec per loop
   ```

Comment: This answer is a great service to humanity.  I was using list comprehension and my operation failed to finish in 25 minutes; then I switched to set subtraction and it finished in 24 seconds.  A miraculous improvement far beyond your timeit results.

Comment: WHy number of loops is different for different approaches in Python 3.9?

Comment: Yeah, the comprehensions have issues when both lists are big. E.g., try lists of 10000+. e.g., l1 = [x for x in range(10000); l2 = [x for x in range(100,10100)], optionally with a shuffle. The list comprehension versions are 500-1000x slower. A drawback of the set approach is that the first array must have unique elements. Also the answer appears to be mixing and matching nsec and usecs.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison. It could be interesting to mentioned that the difference of duration between list comprehension from Donut and set subtraction from Arkku is a factor *n*, *n* being the length of the list you subtract from.
In the example chosen, it last 4 times longer because the second list has 4 elements, but if your second list contains 1000 elements, it will take 1000 times longer... 
In cases with long list, the list comprehension is just not usable.

Comment: Great answer. just note when using the `set` solutions, the order of the returned value is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 33):

Expanding on Donut's answer and the other answers here, you can get even better results by using a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension, and by using a `set` data structure (since the `in` operator is O(n) on a list but O(1) on a set).

So here's a function that would work for you:

```
def filter_list(full_list, excludes):
    s = set(excludes)
    return (x for x in full_list if x not in s)
```

The result will be an iterable that will lazily fetch the filtered list.  If you need a real list object (e.g. if you need to do a `len()` on the result), then you can easily build a list like so:

```
filtered_list = list(filter_list(full_list, excludes))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it solves O(N) complexity problem of *in* test and keeps the order of the full_list.
I would suggest to keep list comprehension format for lisibility:

excludes_set = set(excludes_list)
filtered_list = [x for x in full_list if x not in excludes_set]

Answer (score 32):

Use the Python set type.   That would be the most Pythonic.  :)

Also, since it's native, it should be the most optimized method too.

See:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

http://docs.python.org/library/sets.htm (for older python)

```
# Using Python 2.7 set literal format.
# Otherwise, use: l1 = set([1,2,6,8])
#
l1 = {1,2,6,8}
l2 = {2,3,5,8}
l3 = l1 - l2
```

Comment: When using sets it should be noted that the output of is ordered, i.e. {1,3,2} becomes {1,2,3} and {"A","C","B"} becomes {"A","B","C"} and you might not want to have that.

Comment: this method will not work if list `l1` includes repeated elements.

Answer (score 13):

use  [Set Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) {x for x in l2} or set(l2) to get set, then use [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get list

```
l2set = set(l2)
l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2set]
```

benchmark test code:

```
import time

l1 = list(range(1000*10 * 3))
l2 = list(range(1000*10 * 2))

l2set = {x for x in l2}

tic = time.time()
l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2set]
toc = time.time()
diffset = toc-tic
print(diffset)

tic = time.time()
l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
toc = time.time()
difflist = toc-tic
print(difflist)

print("speedup %fx"%(difflist/diffset))
```

benchmark test result:

```
0.0015058517456054688
3.968189239501953
speedup 2635.179227x
```

Comment: `l2set = set( l2 )` instead of `l2set = { x for x in l2 }`

Comment: Nice soultion! But it must be kept in mind, that it only works with hashable objects.

Answer (score 9):

Alternate Solution  :

```
reduce(lambda x,y : filter(lambda z: z!=y,x) ,[2,3,5,8],[1,2,6,8])
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this method? It looks like it's more complex and harder to read without much benefit.

Comment: That might seem complex . Reduce is very flexible and can be used for a lot of purposes. It is known as fold . reduce is actually foldl . Suppose you want to add more complex stuff in it then it will be possible in this function but list comprehension which is the selected best answer will only get you an output of the same type i.e list and probably of the same length while with folds you could change the output type as well . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29 . This solution is n*m or less complexity. Others may or may not be better though.

Comment: reduce (function , list , initial accumulator (which can be of any type))

Answer (score 8):

### Using `set.difference()`:

You can use [`set.difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) to get new set with elements in the set that are not in the others. i.e. `set(A).difference(B)` will return set with items present in `A`, but not in `B`. For example:

```
>>> set([1,2,6,8]).difference([2,3,5,8])
{1, 6}
```

It is a **functional approach to get `set` difference** mentioned in [*Arkku's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/2063361) *(which uses arithmetic subtraction `-` operator for set difference)*.

Since [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) are unordered, you'll loose the ordering of elements from initial list. *(continue reading next section if you want to maintain the orderig of elements)*

### Using *List Comprehension* with `set` based lookup

If you want **to maintain the ordering from initial list**, then [*Donut's list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211228/2063361) based answer will do the trick. However, you can **get better performance** from the accepted answer **by using `set` internally** for checking whether element is present in other list. For example:

```
l1, l2 = [1,2,6,8], [2,3,5,8]
s2 = set(l2)  # Type-cast `l2` to `set`

l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in s2]
                             #   ^ Doing membership checking on `set` s2
```

If you are interested in knowing why membership checking is faster is `set` when compared to `list`, please read this: [*What makes sets faster than lists?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8929284/2063361)

---

### Using `filter()` and *lambda expression*

Here's another **alternative using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with the *lambda expression***. Adding it here just for reference, but it is not performance efficient:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,6,8]
>>> l2 = set([2,3,5,8])

#     v  `filter` returns the a iterator object. Here I'm type-casting 
#     v  it to `list` in order to display the resultant value
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x not in l2, l1))
[1, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `filterfalse` *without* lambda-expression

When using functions like [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) or [`filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) and similar from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) you can usually save performance by avoiding `lambda`-expressions and using already existing functions. Instances of `list` and `set` defines a [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)-method to use for containment checks. The `in`-operator calls this method under the hood, so using `x in l2` can be replaced by `l2.__contains__(x)`. Usually this replacement is not really prettier but in this specific case it allows us to gain better performance than using a `lambda`-expression, when used in combination with `filterfalse`:

```py
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 6, 8]
>>> l2 = [2, 3, 5, 8]
>>> list(filterfalse(l2.__contains__, l1))
[1, 6]
```

`filterfalse` creates an iterator yielding all elements that returns `false` when used as an argument for `l2.__contains__`.

Sets has a faster implementation of `__contains__` so even better is:

```py
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 6, 8]
>>> l2 = set([2, 3, 5, 8])
>>> list(filterfalse(l2.__contains__, l1))
[1, 6]
```

#### Performance

Using list:

```sh
$  python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import filterfalse; l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "list(filterfalse(l2.__contains__, l1))"
500000 loops, best of 5: 522 nsec per loop
```

Using set:

```sh
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import filterfalse; l1 = [1,2,6,8]; l2 = set([2,3,5,8]);" "list(filterfalse(l2.__contains__, l1))"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 359 nsec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

The set approach is the best if you WANT THAT behavior. If you do not want to remove all instances of elements in list l1 that exist only once in l2, those set operations will lead to incorrect results. Suppose you have repeating elements in l1 , and probably even in l2 and want an actual difference of the two lists l1 - l2, while maintaining the order of remaining elements:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2]
l2 = [1, 2, 2, 5]
_ = [l1.remove(item) for item in l2 if item in l1] # discard return value
print(l1) # [3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5]
```

> 1. Careful that this will be significantly slower than set operation use this only if your use case needs it
> 2. If you dont want to modify the original list - create a copy of the list first

Answer (score 1):

## Sets versus list comprehension benchmark on Python 3.8

(adding up to Moinuddin Quadri's benchmarks)

tldr: Use **Arkku's set solution**, it's even faster than promised in comparison!

### Checking existing files against a list

In my example I found it to be **40 times (!)** faster to use **Arkku's set solution** than the **pythonic list comprehension** for a real world application of checking existing filenames against a list.

#### List comprehension:

```
%%time
import glob
existing = [int(os.path.basename(x).split(".")[0]) for x in glob.glob("*.txt")]
wanted = list(range(1, 100000))
[i for i in wanted if i not in existing]
```

Wall time: 28.2 s

#### Sets

```
%%time
import glob
existing = [int(os.path.basename(x).split(".")[0]) for x in glob.glob("*.txt")]
wanted = list(range(1, 100000))
set(wanted) - set(existing)
```

Wall time: 689 ms

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1=[1,2,6,8]
l2=[2,3,5,8]
r=[]
for x in l1:
    if x in l2:
        continue
    r=r+[x]
print(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

### Maintaining order by exploiting the ordered property of dicts (Python 3.7+)

Note: the reference implementation of `dicts` in Python 3.6 maintains keys in their order of insertion order, but this is not guaranteed by the specification. For 3.7 and up, this guarantee was added.

The keys of a `dict` function as a sort of `set`; duplicates are implicitly filtered out, and lookup is efficient due to hashing. Therefore, we can implement a "set difference" by building a dict using `l1` as keys, and then removing any keys that appear in `l2`. This maintains order and uses a fast algorithm, but incurs a fair amount of constant-factor overhead.

```
d = dict.fromkeys(l1)
for i in l2:
    try:
        del d[i]
    except KeyError:
        pass
l3 = list(d.keys())
```