# How to get element not included in combinations list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have generator with 3 pretty big chunks. I am creating combinations of 2 elements from it, but then in some part of code I need third part (the one not included in combinations). How should I do it? I don't need the simplest or the prettiest solution, I need the fastest solution possible.

Example:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
gen = chunks(a, 2) # this is not important
for x in combinations(gen, 2):
    # let's say we have x = ['a','b'] and I want to get 'c'
    # I know it is possible to put all generator elements in list and get 'c' 
    # with for loop or set, but I don't if this is the fastest way to get it
```

Comment: Please include a minimal example in your question.

Comment: @wwii I hope it is more clear what I want now.

Comment: What does ```gen``` produce?

Comment: `[['a'],['b'],['c']]`

Comment: I still don't get it. What is b? Can you be more explicit about what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: See [Remove all the elements that occur in 1 list from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-1-list-from-another).  Is ```gen``` an actual generator or a ```list```?  If it is a generator, there isn't a way to *use* the sequence that the combinations are made from to extract the missing element.

Comment: It is generator, I create it with yield. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe ```set(chunks(a,2)).difference(x)``` - but you would have to create a new set each time.

Answer (score 0):

As an efficient way i suggest define a function that you could use it multitime and get the difference with `set` because its a **pythonic** and **fast** way :

```
>>> def diff(test_array=[],main_array=['a','b','c']):
...  return set(main_array).difference(set(test_array)).pop()
... 
>>> diff(['a','b'])
'c'
```