# dropping rows from dataframe based on a "not in" condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop rows from a pandas dataframe when the value of the date column is in a list of dates. The following code doesn't work:

```
a=['2015-01-01' , '2015-02-01']

df=df[df.datecolumn not in a]
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 325, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Dataframe.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas.DataFrame.isin).

`pandas.Dateframe.isin` will return boolean values depending on whether each element is inside the list `a` or not. You then invert this with the `~` to convert `True` to `False` and vice versa.

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['2015-01-01' , '2015-02-01']

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2015-01-01' , '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01' , '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01' , '2015-06-01']})

print(df)
#         date
#0  2015-01-01
#1  2015-02-01
#2  2015-03-01
#3  2015-04-01
#4  2015-05-01
#5  2015-06-01

df = df[~df['date'].isin(a)]

print(df)
#         date
#2  2015-03-01
#3  2015-04-01
#4  2015-05-01
#5  2015-06-01
```

Comment: You probably mean [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin), not `DataFrame.isin`. You're comparing for a column, not an entire df.

Comment: I have an error when I tried this `df = df[~df.isin(a)]`
`SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x11a227690> returned a result with an error set`

Answer (score 66):

You can use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
df = df[~df.datecolumn.isin(a)]
```

While the error message suggests that `all()` or `any()` can be used, they are useful only when you want to reduce the result into a single Boolean value. That is however not what you are trying to do now, which is to test the membership of every values in the Series against the external list, and keep the results intact (i.e., a Boolean Series which will then be used to slice the original DataFrame).

You can read more about this in the [Gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).