# Compare PandaS DataFrames and return rows that are missing from the first one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataFrames and want to compare them and return rows from the first one (df1) that are not in the second one (df2).  I found a way to compare them and return the differences, but can't figure out how to return only missing ones from df1.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"City" : ["Chicago", "San Franciso", "Boston"] , 
"State" : ["Illinois", "California", "Massachusett"] } )

df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"City" : ["Chicago",  "Mmmmiami", "Dallas" , "Omaha"] , 
"State" : ["Illinois", "Florida", "Texas", "Nebraska"] } )



df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
blah = df.reindex(idx)
```

Comment: You could be a little more specific. What is the question? Where are the problem? ...

Answer (score 18):

Building on @EdChum's suggestion:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', suffixes=('','_y'), indicator=True)
rows_in_df1_not_in_df2 = df[df['_merge']=='left_only'][df1.columns]

rows_in_df1_not_in_df2

|Index |City        |State       |
|------|------------|------------|
|1     |San Franciso|California  |
|2     |Boston      |Massachusett|
```

EDIT: incorporate @RobertPeters suggestion

Comment: should be `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', suffixes = ('','_y') ,indicator=True)` to work

Answer (score 11):

IIUC then if you're using pandas version `0.17.0` then you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) and set `indicator=True`:

```
In [80]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"City" : ["Chicago", "San Franciso", "Boston"] , 
"State" : ["Illinois", "California", "Massachusett"] } )
​
df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"City" : ["Chicago",  "Mmmmiami", "Dallas" , "Omaha"] , 
"State" : ["Illinois", "Florida", "Texas", "Nebraska"] } )
pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', indicator=True)

Out[80]:
           City         State      _merge
0       Chicago      Illinois        both
1  San Franciso    California   left_only
2        Boston  Massachusett   left_only
3      Mmmmiami       Florida  right_only
4        Dallas         Texas  right_only
5         Omaha      Nebraska  right_only
```

This adds a column to indicator whether the rows are only present in either lhs or rhs

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a list comprehension and compare the rows to return the missing elements:

```
dif_list = [x for x in list(df1['City'].unique()) if x not in list(df2['City'].unique())]
```

returns:

```
['San Franciso', 'Boston']
```

You could then get a dataframe with just the rows that are different:

```
dfdif = df1[(df1['City'].isin(dif_list))]
```

Comment: this is a nice way of seeing which rows are missing by index as well - particularly when unique rows are identifiable only with a multi-index - eg.: `dif = [ x for x in list(df2.index) if not x in list( df1.index ) ]`

Answer (score 2):

If you're on pandas < 0.17.0

You could work your way up like

```
In [182]: df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='City', how='outer')

In [183]: df
Out[183]:
           City       State_x   State_y
0       Chicago      Illinois  Illinois
1  San Franciso    California       NaN
2        Boston  Massachusett       NaN
3      Mmmmiami           NaN   Florida
4        Dallas           NaN     Texas
5         Omaha           NaN  Nebraska

In [184]: df.ix[df['State_y'].isnull(),:]
Out[184]:
           City       State_x State_y
1  San Franciso    California     NaN
2        Boston  Massachusett     NaN
```