# I want to drop one Dataframe from another (the first df is a subset of the second)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to analyze changes in tuition costs for private schools in urban settings vs private schools in rural settings.

I have a dataframe with tuition costs of all private schools in the US through time (`tuit_cost`). The dataframe `tuit_cost` contains columns of historical tuition costs as well as two columns titled `['State','City/Town Name']`.

I also have a separate dataframe of private schools that are classified as being in 'Urban' areas (`urban_schools`). This dataframe has only two columns -- `['State','City/Town Name']`.

I merged the dataframes in order to create a dataframe with only the urban schools' historical tuition data.

```
urban_school_tuit = pd.merge(urban_schools, tuit_cost, how='left', left_on= ['State','City/Town Name'], right_on=['State','City/Town Name']).dropna()
```

Now I want to create a dataframe with only the rural schools' historical tuition data by dropping all of the rows in `urban_school_tuit` from `tuit_cost`.

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried dataframe.subtract ? Documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html

Comment: Also interested in your study...I have a child in boarding school. Will you publish someplace eventually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe.

Comment: @mba12 -- dataframe.subtract returns a view of ``tuit_cost`` that has '0.0' values across all the rows in ``urban_schools`` and NaN values across all the rows that i want to use in the ``rural_schools`` dataframe I want to create. Any suggestions on how to select these rows and populate them with the original data they contained in ``tuit_cost``??    (As of now I do not have plans to publish -- I will let you know if that changes.. thanks for your interest!)

Comment: @3novak the issue I was having was that the indices were not the same so I could not use ``is in`` (as recommended by most of the answers in the question you referenced)

Comment: Any update on this research proposal? :^)

Comment: Has this been published yet? Very interested in the findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to patch this together to create the desired dataframe (in Python 3)...

```
rural_schools = tuit_cost.drop(list(zip(urban_schools['State'],urban_schools['City/Town Name'])))
```

Open to any further guidance or suggestions.