# Joining dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, join

For the following dataframes in Python:

```
 Yref = pd.read_csv(rootDir + 'data/trailerClassificationData/C'+str(2)+'_withinShotAggr_'+withinShotAggr+'_btwshotAggr_'+btwShotAggr+'.csv',sep=',')
 Y = pd.read_csv(rootDir + 'data/trailerClassificationData/C'+str(3)+'_withinShotAggr_'+withinShotAggr+'_btwshotAggr_'+btwShotAggr+'.csv',sep=',')
```

where `Y` and `Yref` are some target classification outputs:

```
Yref

   movieId Action Comedy Drama Horror
0  93797     1      0     1      0
1  25899     0      1     0      0
2  5673      0      1     1      0
3  86308     0      1     0      0
4  3577      0      0     1      0
5  3575      0      0     1      0
...
7100 rows × 5 columns
```

and similarly for Y

```
Y

   movieId Action Comedy Drama Horror
0  93797     1      0     1      0
1  1222      0      0     1      0
2  5673      0      1     1      0
3  86308     0      1     0      0
4  3577      0      0     1      0
5  3575      0      0     1      0

7136 rows × 5 columns
```

as it can be seen the two outputs have **different number of rows**. Therefore, the first question is **how to join the two dataframes with on = 'movieId' and how='inner' ?**

```
Yjoin = Yref.join(Y,how='inner',on='movieId')
```

gave me this error.  `columns overlap but no suffix specified`.  I managed to solve the first problem using:

```
  Yjoin = Yref.merge(Y,on='movieId',how='inner')
  Yjoin = Yres.ix[:,0:5]
  Yjoin.rename(columns={'Action_x':'Action','Comedy_x':'Comedy_x','Drama_x':'Drama','Horror_x':'Horror'}, inplace=True)
```

Once done, `X` is a dataframe similar to `Y` with similar rows but without the key 'movieId'.

```
   test1     test2     test3          test4         test5
0  0.038039  0.212623  4.052835e-02   5.210721e-02  0.004591
1  0.054539  0.257145  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00  0.115421
2  0.002842  0.209085  1.114923e-02   3.844100e-02  0.024544
3  0.136707  0.377181  0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00  0.055199
....
7136 rows × 5 columns
```

I need to remove the deleted rows from `Yjoin` **also from X** so X will have the same length 7100*5. At the end of the day, Y and X will have the same number of rows 7100.

thanks for your comments

Comment: Sorry are you after merge? `res = Yref.merge(Y,how='inner',on='movieId')`

Comment: thanks. very similar to this but i do not need to merge the two tables on column-side as they are the same. I just want to remove they rows from `Y` that does not exist in `Yref` given the `movieId` as the key.

Comment: you mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe?

Comment: You should say what error it gives you. "an" is not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated my question. I solved the first problem, now I need to answer the second question.