# Pandas left outer join exclusion

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

How can I do a left outer join, excluding the intersection, in Pandas?

I have 2 pandas dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['finance', 'finance', 'finance', 'accounting', 'IT'], 'col2' : ['az', 'bh', '', '', '']}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['finance', 'finance', 'finance', 'finance', 'finance'], 'col2' : ['', 'az', '', '', '']})
```

df1

```
    col1    col2
0   finance az
1   finance bh
2   finance 
3   accounting  
4   IT
```

df2

```
    col1    col2
0   finance 
1   finance az
2   finance 
3   finance 
4   finance
```

As you can see the dataframe has blank values as well. I tried using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe) and its not giving me the result I want.

```
common = df1.merge(df2,on=['col1','col2'])
df3=df1[(~df1.col1.isin(common.col1))&(~df1.col2.isin(common.col2))]
```

I want the output to look something like

```
    col1    col2
3   accounting  
4   IT
```

Comment: Did you try `common = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['col1', 'col2'])`?

Comment: yes, its giving me the same results that i am getting with common = df1.merge(df2,on=['col1','col2'])

Comment: Do you mind posting your current output?

Answer (score 13):

Pandas left outer join exclusion can be achieved by setting pandas merge's indicator=True. Then filter by the indicator in _merge column.

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2[['col1']],on=['col1'],how="outer",indicator=True)
df=df[df['_merge']=='left_only']
# this following line is just formating
df = df.reset_index()[['col1', 'col2']]
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
0   accounting  
1   IT
```

## ==================================

====The following is an example showing the mechanism====

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['0', '1'],
                     'key2': [-1, -1],
                     'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                     })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['0', '1'],
                      'key2': [1, -1], 
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1']
                     })
```

:

```
df1
```

Output:

```
    A   key1    key2
0   A0  0       -1
1   A1  1       -1
```

:

```
df2
```

Output:

```
    B   key1    key2
0   B0  0       1
1   B1  1       -1
```

:

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['key1','key2'],how="outer",indicator=True)
```

:

Output:

```
     A  key1    key2    B   _merge
0   A0  0   -1  NaN left_only
1   A1  1   -1  B1  both
2   NaN 0   1   B0  right_only
```

:With the above indicators in the `_merge` column. you can select rows in one dataframe but not in another.

```
df=df[df['_merge']=='left_only']
df
```

Output:

```
    A   key1    key2    B   _merge
0   A0  0   -1  NaN left_only
```

Answer (score 4):

A one liner for this based on Bin's answer may be:

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2[['col1']],on=['col1'],how="outer",indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"')
```

Answer (score 0):

This fails because you're independently checking for a match in `col1` & `col2`, and excluding a match on either. The empty strings match the empty strings in the `finance` rows.

You'd want:

```
df3 = df1[(~df1.col1.isin(common.col1))|(~df1.col2.isin(common.col2))]
df3
Out[150]: 
         col1 col2
1     finance   bh
3  accounting     
4          IT
```

To get the rows in `df1` not in `df2` .

To get specifically

```
df3
    col1    col2
3   accounting  
4   IT
```

you might try just selecting those with a non-matching `col1`.

```
df3 = df1[~df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]
df3
Out[172]: 
         col1 col2
3  accounting     
4          IT
```

To independently check for a match in `col1` & `col2` and exclude a match on either while having `NaN`s compare unequal/never count as a match, you could use

```
df3 = df1[(~df1.col1.isin(common.col1)|df1.col1.isnull())&(~df1.col2.isin(common.col2)|df1.col2.isnull())]
df3
Out[439]: 
         col1 col2
3  accounting  NaN
4          IT  NaN
```

assuming you're working with actual `NaN`s, either `None` or `np.nan`, in your actual data, instead of empty strings as in this example. If the latter, you'll need to add

```
df1.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df2.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

first.

Comment: doesn't solve the purpose and not helpful for the original question

Comment: @Enthusiast Edited, thoughts?

Comment: It only takes one column col1, whereas i want to consider all columns

Comment: @Enthusiast Could you clarify, either here or in your main post, what you want to consider about all columns? If you want all rows that don't match in full, then, for this two-column case, you want the first option I posted, with the `1     finance   bh` row. If you want all rows that don't share any value with any row in the other df, you want the empty df the method in your initial post gave you. Do you want to do one of those while having blank values always compare unequal? I'll edit momentarily, on that assumption, but if not that's really my last guess at your goal without clarification.