# How to remove rows in a Pandas dataframe if the same row exists in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
 df1 = row1;row2;row3
 df2 = row4;row5;row6;row2
```

I want my output dataframe to only contain the rows unique in df1, i.e.:

```
df_out = row1;row3
```

How do I get this most efficiently?

This code does what I want, but using 2 for-loops:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3],1:[10,20,30]})
b = pd.DataFrame({0:[0,1,2,3],1:[0,1,20,3]})

match_ident = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    found=False
    for j in range(0,len(b)):
        if a[0][i]==b[0][j]:
            if a[1][i]==b[1][j]:
                found=True
    match_ident.append(not(found))

a = a[match_ident]
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, since I don't have an unique id which maps to the common values in both dataframes.

Comment: Can't flag it, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You an use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `indicator` and outer join, [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering and then remove helper column with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

DataFrames are joined on all columns, so `on` parameter can be omit.

```
print (pd.merge(a,b, indicator=True, how='outer')
         .query('_merge=="left_only"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1))
   0   1
0  1  10
2  3  30
```

Comment: It would be better to use 'left' join in this case. If we're joining on an index or column(s) rather than full dataframe there might be missing values in other coluimns. If so, int values in such column would be converted to float thus loosing precision (imagine you have a long int index to database there). Using left join would guarantee that all columns in left df would not be converted. Also left join would preserve key order rather than sorting them lexicographically.

Answer (score 20):

You could convert `a` and `b` into `Index`s, then use the [`Index.isin` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) to determine which rows are shared in common:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3],1:[10,20,30]})
b = pd.DataFrame({0:[0,1,2,3],1:[0,1,20,3]})

a_index = a.set_index([0,1]).index
b_index = b.set_index([0,1]).index
mask = ~a_index.isin(b_index)
result = a.loc[mask]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   0   1
0  1  10
2  3  30
```