# How to remove rows in a Pandas dataframe if there exits matches across a set of columns in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of people in a dataframe, I need the list of people that do not occur in the main dataset. Currently I am checking against first and last name.

`data_to_check_dataset` is the input data that needs to be checked , it contains many columns but currently I only need to check against `first_name` , `last_name`.

|  | first_name | last_name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | Apple | ... |
| 1 | Alice | test | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10000 | Paul | test | ... |

sometimes the data fields can be entirely blank and are read as nan values.

|  | first_name | last_name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James comp | nan | ... |
| 1 | Paul ltd | nan | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10000 | Paul other | nan | ... |

The dataframe I am checking against  `current_people_dataset` : , it contains many columns I have renamed the name columns to   `first_name` , `last_name`. Its null values are blank for some reason, I think because

|  | first_name | last_name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f_A | l_A | ... |
| 1 | B |  | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 900000 | paul | smith | ... |

The `data_to_check_dataset` is always smaller then the `current_people_dataset`.
Column ordering is not fixed and can change depending on here the data is loaded in from.

currently I have been trying to adapt the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706892/1148628).

```
new_people_names = (pd.merge(data_to_check_dataset,current_people_dataset, indicator=True, how='outer')
         .query('_merge=="left_only"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1))
```

This raises `ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` error when comparing colunmns.

Comment: sorry I have no ideas why it delisted the answer , I did not delist it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what error is saying so one way is to typecase first_name and last_name of both df's to string by using `astype()`:

```
data_to_check_dataset[['first_name','last_name']]=data_to_check_dataset[['first_name','last_name']].astype(str)
current_people_dataset[['first_name','last_name']]=current_people_dataset[['first_name','last_name']].astype(str)
```

Finally chain `replace()` to your current method for converting string nan back to real NaN:

```
new_people_names = (pd.merge(data_to_check_dataset,current_people_dataset, indicator=True, how='outer',on=['first_name','last_name'])
         .query('_merge=="left_only"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1)
         .replace('nan',float('NaN'),regex=True))
```