# Pandas: How to filter rows in dataframe which is not equal to the combination of columns in other dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Below are the two dataframes. I was trying to filter rows in df_2 which are not equal to the combination of df_count rows. How can I achieve this objective?

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name_1':['tom', 'jack', 'tom', 'jack', 'tom', 'nick', 'tom', 'jack', 'tom', 'jack'],
    'Name_2':['sam', 'sam', 'ruby', 'sam','sam', 'jack', 'ruby', 'sam','ruby', 'sam']})
df_count = df_1.groupby(['Name_1','Name_2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'}).sort_values(['count'], ascending = False)
df_count = df_count.head(2)
df_count = df_count[['Name_1','Name_2']]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name_1':['tom', 'nick', 'tom', 'jack', 'tom', 'nick', 'tom', 'jack'],
    'Name_2':['sam', 'mike', 'ruby', 'sam', 'sam', 'jack', 'ruby', 'sam'],
    'Salary':[200, 500, 1000, 7000, 100, 300, 1200, 900],
    'Currency':['AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CAD', 'INR', 'USD']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.merge(df_2,df_count, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge=="left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
  Name_1 Name_2  Salary Currency
0    tom    sam     200      AUD
1    tom    sam     100      GBP
2   nick   mike     500      CAD
7   nick   jack     300      CAD
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706485/how-to-remove-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-if-the-same-row-exists-in-another-dataf).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I didnt think of merge option.