# Check which rows of pandas exist in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Data Frames of different sizes (at least 500,000 rows in both of them). For simplicity, you can call them `df1` and `df2` . I'm interested in finding the rows of `df1` which are not present in `df2`. It is not necessary that any of the data frames would be the subset of the other. Also, the order of the rows does not matter.

For example, `i`th observation in `df1` may be `j`th observation in `df2` and I need to consider it as being present (order won't matter). Another important thing is that both data frames may contain null values (so the operation has to work also for that).

A simple example of both data frame would be

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 100], 'col2' : [10, 11, NaN, 50}) 

df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100], 'col2' : [20, 21, NaN, 13, 14, 50]})
```

in this case the solution would be

```
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2 ], 'col2' : [10, 11]})
```

Please note that in reality, both data frames have 15 columns (exactly same columns names, exact same data type). Also, I'm using Python 2.7 on Jupyter Notebook on windows 7. I have used Pandas built in function `df1.isin(df2)` but it does not provide the accurate results that I want.

Moreover, I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe/47107164#47107164)

but this assumes that one data frame is the subset of another which is not necessarily true in my case.

Comment: Is all your data numeric?

Comment: Yes Sir it is..The exact data type is float64 for all the columns of both data frames.

Comment: In your example output, where does the [10, 11] come from for col2 - it looks like 10 and 11 are in df1, but not df2.

Comment: also, are all the floats >= 0 or `np.nan` ?

Comment: Some of the values are NaN. Most of them are >=0 though.

Comment: The output should be the first two rows of df1 because they are not present in df2. The next two rows of df1 are present in df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 100], 'col2' : [10, 11, np.nan, 50]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100], 'col2' : [20, 21, np.nan, 13, 14, 50]})

x = set(map(tuple, df1.fillna(-1).values)) - set(map(tuple, df2.fillna(-1).values))
# {(1.0, 10.0), (2.0, 11.0)}

pd.DataFrame(list(x), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

If you have `np.nan` data in your result, it'll come through as -1, but you can easily convert back. Assumes you won't have negative numbers in your underlying data [if so, replace by some impossible value].

The reason for the complication is that `np.nan` == `np.nan` is considered `False`.

Comment: May I ask why are you using tuple in Map, the reason for saying that is I have 15 columns in actual, not 2...So maybe this works for 2 columns but that's just a short example...

Comment: @SibghatUllah, sure np. Feel free to accept if it helped (tick on left).

Answer (score 1):

Here is on solution

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.loc[df2.col1.isin(df1.col1)]],keys=[1,2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).loc[1]
Out[892]: 
   col1  col2
0     1  10.0
1     2  11.0
```

Comment: nice, better than mine :) +1. I wonder how it works given `np.nan` == `np.nan` is False.

Comment: @jpp Guess drop_duplicate will skipna and check all real object