# Drop rows from a data frame dosen't work correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df_semi_sup2` and `df_confident_inst_no` and I want to drop all instances existing in `df_confident_inst_no` from `df_semi_sup2`. I made researches about that and I found the necessary code, but it dosen't give the results that I'm waiting for.

Here is the code :

```
for index, row in df_confident_inst_no.iterrows() :

    df_semi_sup2= df_semi_sup2.drop(df_semi_sup2.index[index])
```

Can anyone help me find the problem in such code ?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe) (works if data structure is identical which you don't tell us):

```
df_new = df_semi_sup2[~df_semi_sup2.isin(df_confident_inst_no)].dropna() # No need to loop
```

You can use dropna()'s `how` parameter like so:

‘any’ : If any NA values are present, drop that row or column.

‘all’ : If all values are NA, drop that row or column.

Comment: Yes in fact data structure is identical. Your answer solved the problem perfectly ! Thanks!