# Pandas Identifying and Removing Similar/Duplicate Rows by Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database table, that has an external process automatically inserting rows every so often. Because of the nature of the data, I need to be vigilant in detecting any possible 'duplicates' (It's actually only similar rows, because only certain columns are important) and removing them. I plan to use a database query to identify all similar rows into a dataframe and then sort and create a dataframe subset of 'keep' rows. The Idea is using a left join from original dataframe to the 'keep' dataframe and Boolean statement to identify the rows that need to be deleted per [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe). Can you tell me if I'm on the right track? I want to be very cautions about the logic deleting records from my database.

Original Dataframe looks like this:

```
   ID Account Type  Date       RowID
0  12  GOB     H    11/12/18   Az123
1  12  GOB     H    11/12/18   Az125
2  12  JPG     H    11/15/18   Az175
3  12  JPG     H    11/17/18   Az189
4  15  BLU     H    11/1/18    Ax127
5  15  BLU     D    11/18/18   Ax135
6  15  BLU     H    11/8/18    Ax175
```

It's important to keep a single record for each ID/Account combination, with preference to accounts with Type D first, and then by Oldest Date.
Below is the desired keep subset.

Desired Keep Subset

```
   ID Account Type  Date       RowID
0  15  BLU     D    11/18/18   Ax135
1  12  GOB     H    11/12/18   Az123
2  12  JPG     H    11/15/18   Az175
```

Code: **Edited with the help of W-B**

```
df = pd.read_sql(similar_rows_sql)
df['helpkey']=df.Type.eq('D')
keep_df = df.sort_values(['Date']).sort_values(
          ['helpkey'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID','Account'], keep='first')
df_all = df.merge(keep_df, how='left', indicator=True)
df_remove = df_all.loc[df_all['_merge']== 'left_only']
for x in df_remove[RowID]:
    cursor.execute(remove_duplicate_sql, x)
connection.commit()
```

**Type Concern Removed Thanks to W-B**

My only remaining concern is this logic is pythonic and accurate to my intentions. Can anyone put my concerns to rest that this is accurate?

Comment: I've been using this version for a few days now and I think I'm comfortable with it. I will mark W-B as answer because he helped me solve the sorting issue which was the only known issue I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a helpkey

```
df['helpkey']=df.Type.eq('D')# return T when it is D , so we sort the helpkey , make sure D always at the end 

df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values(['ID','helpkey','Date']).drop_duplicates(['ID','Account'],keep='last')
Out[163]: 
   ID Account Type       Date  RowID  helpkey
1  12     GOB    H 2018-11-12  Az125    False
3  12     JPG    H 2018-11-17  Az189    False
5  15     BLU    D 2018-11-18  Ax135     True
```

Comment: Thank you! The use of the help key column does help me ensure I'm getting the right duplicates. I had to modify your example slightly to actually get the Desired 'Keep' Subset, but it is definitely the right approach.


`keep_df = df.sort_values(['Date']).sort_values(['helpkey'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID','Account'], keep='first')`