# Pandas merge disregarding common items

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Good day,

I wish to do pandas merge on in SQL fashion where I get items from set **A** which are not present in set **B**. How to do this with Pandas?

```
select * from a 
  left join 
 b
 on a.key1 = b.key1 and a.key2= b.key2
 where b.key1 is NULL or b.key2 is NULL
```

Sql example from [javarevisited.blogspot.com](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_HsHikmChBI/VmQGJjLKgyI/AAAAAAAAEPw/JaLnV0bsbEo/s1600/sql%2Bjoins%2Bguide%2Band%2Bsyntax.jpg).

Closest what I've found is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe), yet feels 'unPandas' and gets quite lengthy with multiple joining keys.

My best 'work around': Inner join on **A** and **B** and then drop common elements from A. Something akin to:

```
 common = pd.merge(a, b, how='inner', left_on='key', right_on='key')
 new_a = a[~a['key']isin(common['key']]
```

So any neater way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge doing a left excluding join.

[image: left-excluding join]

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), the image above is taken from this answer.

```
(a.merge(b, on='key', how='left', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge == "left_only"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought outer gets both A and B disregarding common, but I wish to have only A set. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, sorry, mindfart. I'll update the answer in a sec =)

Comment: Anyway, I strongly suggest again to have a look at the posted link. It is an extremely well written tutorial on merging in pandas