# Python: how two find out the different rows from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes table1 and table2:

table1

[image: table1]

table2

[image: table2]

I want to compare table1 with table2 and return miss rows from each other of table 1 and table 2.

Comment: add some example to show your expactations

Comment: It seems like it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Comment: Where are you at that you're stuck? Have you got further than screenshotting some intput - eg have you got those two tables into two dataframes already and tried something that doesn't work?

Comment: `df1.loc[~df1[col].isn(df2[col])]`

Comment: use: `df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge',axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
only_in_1 = table1.merge(table2.assign(key=1), how='left')
only_in_1 = only_in_1[pd.isna(only_in_1['key'])].drop('key', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = table1
df2 = table2

df_inner = df1.merge(df2, on = ['A', 'B', 'C'], how = 'inner')
df_outer = df1.merge(df2, on = ['A', 'B', 'C'], how = 'outer')
df_inner['label'] = np.ones(len(df_inner))
df = df_outer.merge(df_inner, on = ['A', 'B', 'C'], how = 'outer')
df = df[df['label'].isna()]
df = df.drop(['label'], axis = 1)
```