# Only adding new rows from a dataframe to a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Each day I get a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe that has five columns called `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`. I want to add rows that I previously did not receive to a file where I keep the unique rows, called `known_data.csv`. In order to do so, I wrote some code that *should*

1. Load the data from `known_data.csv` as a dataframe called `existing_data`
2. Add a new column called 'existing' to the `existing_data` df
3. Merge the old `existing_data` dataframe with the dataframe called `new_data` on the five columns
4. Check whether `new_data` contains new rows by looking at `merge[merge.existing.isnull()]` (the complement of the new data and the existing data)
5. Append the new rows to the `known_data.csv` file

My code looks like this

```
existing_data = pd.read_csv("known_data.csv")

existing_data['existing'] = 'yes'

merge_data = pd.merge(new_data, existing_data, on = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'], how = 'left')

complement = merge_data[merge_data.existing.isnull()]

del complement['existing']

complement.to_csv("known_data.csv", mode='a', index=False,
                  header=False)
```

Unfortunately, this code does not function as expected: *the complement is never empty*. Even when I receive data that has already been recorded in `known_data.csv`, some of the rows of `new_data` are being appended to the file anyways.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem? Does it have to do with the way I'm reading the file and write to the file?

**Edit:** Adding a new column called `existing` to the `existing_data` dataframe is probably not the best way of checking the complement between `existing_data` and `new_data`. If anyone has a better suggestion that would be hugely appreciated!

**Edit2:** The problem was that although the dataframes looked identical, there were some values that were of a different type. Somehow this error only showed when I tried to merge a subset of the new dataframe for which this was the case.

Comment: what does `complement ` return, did you check it?

Comment: @Datanovice Complement returns rows that are already present in the `known_data.csv` file! I have inspected these rows in the `known_data.csv` file and they appear to be identical

Comment: it's quite hard to write a solution without seing your data (input and expected) just a sample. for now have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a concat operation followed by a drop duplicate.

```
# Concat the two dataframes into a new dataframe holding all the data (memory intensive):
complement = pd.concat([existing_data, new_data], ignore_index=True)

# Remove all duplicates:
complement.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, keep=False)
```

This will first create a dataframe holding all the old and new data and in a second step will delete all duplicate entries. You can also specify certain columns on which to compare the duplicate values only!

See the documentation here:

**concat**
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

**drop_duplicates**
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html