# Get the unique row by comparing the two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have two df's

df1

```
0       1 
1234   mark
4865   john
4866   joseph
7916   stuart
```

df2

```
0       1       2  
1234   mark    test1
4865   john    test2
4866   joseph  test3
```

expected output :

get the unique row comparing from both the dataframe and display the the unique column in df1

df1

```
0       1
7916   stuart
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "_display the unique column in `df1`_"? `df1` has only one column.

Comment: tried merging , outer but i need to remove the rows from df1 when some of its rows matches with the df2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can try as below

```
df1[(~df1['0'].isin(df2['0'])) & (~df1['1'].isin(df2['1']))]
```

```
      0     1
3   7916    stuart
```