# How to get the rest of a dataframe that is not intersected by another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes:

```
df_total
df1
df2
```

Where

```
df2 = pd.merge(df_total, df1[[Portfolio, Value]], on=Portfolio, how = inner)
```

I merge `df_total` and `df1` when the values of `Portfolio` column are the same. This results in `df2`.

How can I get a `df3=` that represents the rest of `df_total` that is not included in the intersection `df2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Comment: No, because when I apply the solution, for example, df_total_rows are not equal to =df2+df3 (rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer doing:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df_total, df1, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

This returns a dataframe like:

```
      col1  col2   col3     _merge
0    ...     ...    ...   left_only
1    ...     ...    ...        both
2    ...     ...    ...  right_only
```

And because I am only interested in "df3= that represents the rest of df_total that is not included in the intersection df2"

```
df2 = df2[df2['_merge'] == "both"].drop('_merge', 1)
df3 = df2[df2['_merge'] == "left_only"].drop('_merge', 1)
```