# Create a set from two datasets with only values from df1 that isnt in df2

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have 2 dataframes.

I want to create a series with locations from df1 that arent duplicated in df2.

i am confused how to do this, any answers appreciated

Comment: Like [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28901683/15497888)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `df_1` :

```py
>>> df_1
    values
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

And `df_2` :

```py
>>> df_2
    values
0   b
1   e
2   f
3   g
```

We can get the values from `df_1` non duplicated in `df_2` using the method [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) like so :

```py
>>> df_1[~df_1['values'].isin(df_2['values'])]
    values
0   a
2   c
3   d
```