# How to compare a dataframe with another df and return new rows from the first df using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to ascertain if values in a **test** dataframe (**df2**) are not appearing in another DF (**df1**). The following are the two DFs:

**df1** created from the following source:

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| AG | Agree |
| SA | Somewhat Agree |
| DG | Disagree |
| SD | Somewhat Disagree |
| NO | None |

**df2** created from the following source:

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| CA | California |
| TX | Texas |
| NO | None |
| NY | New York |

Using **Method 1** (see below), I am getting the expected result, which is:

**Method 1**

`diff_df = df2[~(df2[field1].isin(df1[field1]) & df2[field2].isin(df1[field2]))].reset_index(drop=True)`

This gives me the folllowing **expected** result:

```
  field1               field2
0     CA           California
1     TX                Texas
2     NY             New York
```

**Note:** The duplicate value in **df2** (`NO: None`) gets dropped, too.

However, there is one problem that I am facing: There can be situations when there are different set of **fields** that will need to be compared (eg. there may be a third field **field3** in the equation).

From case to case basis, the **number of fields would vary greatly** over which the user won't have control.

**My problem:**
How do I modify my query so that by comparing the two dataframes I get the expected result?

In the situation as explained, what shuld be the **possible** approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating the dataframe
df1_field1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
df1_field2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df1_field3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'field1':df1_field1,
     'field2':df1_field2,
     'field3':df1_field3,     
    })

df2_field1 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'] 
df2_field2 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df2_field3 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'field1':df2_field1,
     'field2':df2_field2,
     'field3':df2_field3,     
    })

print(df)
print(df2)

df_all = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), on=['field1','field2','field3'], 
                   how='outer', indicator=True)
df_all[df_all['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

it yields:

```
  field1 field2 field3
0      a      a      a
1      b      b      b
2      c      c      c
3      d      d      d
  field1 field2 field3
0      a      a      a
1      c      c      c
2      d      d      d
3      e      e      e

field1  field2  field3  _merge
3   e   e   e   left_only
```

As you can see, it works, and it is just an adaptation of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107164/10193268) in the page you put in the description.