# Drop rows in a dataframe if they do not exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have two dataframes (498 rows and 249 rows)
The index labels are objects
I want to drop the columns which do not appear in the smaller DF so that both are 249 rows

```
INDEX DF1 (249 rows)
AB111  
AB222
AB333
AB444
AB555
AB666
AB777
AB888

INDEX DF2 (498 rows)
AB111 
dd222 
AB222
dd333
AB333
dd666
AB444
dd999
AB555
dd000
AB666
AB777
AB888

uncommon_indices = np.setdiff1d(df_patient_info_train.index.values, df_rnaseq_dropped.values)


uncommom_tolist = uncommon_indices.tolist()


wanted = df_rnaseq_dropped.drop(uncommon_tolist, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

ERROR: .....

```
not found in axis
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
liste1=DF1.index.values.tolist()#list of DF1 index
liste2=DF1.index.values.tolist()#list of DF2 index
in_DF2_notin_DF1=np.setdiff1d(liste2,liste1) # index that exist in DF2 and not exestion in DF 
df.drop(in_DF2_notin_DF1, inplace=True) # drop index in list in_DF2_notin_DF1
```