# Compare two CSV files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two CSV file i need to compare two CSV file.

First CSV file having column code , Aid

Second CSV file having column com_code,Aid

I need to Compare first CSV file code  column values to second CSV file com_code. And results I need  the result of code value which are not there in second CSV file com_code can anyone help please.

| Code | Aid |
| --- | --- |
| 78909 | 111 |
| 75606 | 444 |
| 55678 | 890 |
| 78909 | 111 |

| com_code |  |
| --- | --- |
| 55678 | 778 |
| 49678 | 889 |
| 90667 | 888 |

Output:

| code | Aid |
| --- | --- |
| 78909 | 111 |
| 75606 | 444 |

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. pandas' `merge` function may help.

Comment: df[~df['Code'].isin(df2['com_code'])] and after that use drop_duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Code':[78909,75606,55678,78909], 'Aid' :[111,444,890,111]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'com_code':[55678,49678,90667], 'Aid2' :[778,889,888]})
df2.rename(columns={"com_code": "Code"},inplace=True)
result = df1.merge(df2['Code'],  on='Code',how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop(columns='_merge')
result.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can load csv files to pandas :

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
```

and find several solutions in this similar question : [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)