# Pandas: date range and removed holidays

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a question about date range. I crated somethin like this:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='25/12/2017', end='05/01/2018', freq='B',closed=None)
```

Result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-25', '2017-12-26', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
           '2017-12-29', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03',
           '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=247, freq='B')
```

I need to remove 3 date: 2017-12-25, 2017-12-27 and 2018-01-04. I was looking for formulas that could help me but I didn't find the correct one. I also tried to change all of this into list but then I couldn't use remove formula because it didn't find the value in list... Anyone has idea how to fix it ?

Thanks All!

Comment: Why those dates in particular?

Comment: It doesn't really matters. The point is that I need to pick the date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition

Comment: and If I don't want to make a df, what else I could use ?

Comment: ok, it works too :D Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want but if you want only business days then you can use the following code:

pd.bdate_range('2018/1/1', '2018/12/31').date