# How to union two dataframes but giving preference to one if it has data in the same month pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, one with an estimated daily value, and another with the closed value for the month.

I need to show the estimated daily value ONLY when the closed value for the month does not exist.

Example:

**df1:**

| **DATA** | **ID** | **VALUE** | **DSC** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | 123 | 10 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-02-31 | 123 | 20 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-03-31 | 999 | 30 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-04-31 | 999 | 40 | CLOSED MONTH |

**df2:**

| **DATA** | **ID** | **VALUE** | **DSC** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | 123 | 50 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-02-31 | 123 | 60 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-03-31 | 123 | 70 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-04-31 | 123 | 80 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-03-20 | 123 | 90 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-03-25 | 123 | 100 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-04-30 | 999 | 120 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-05-02 | 999 | 150 | ESTIMATED DAY |
| 2022-05-03 | 999 | 200 | ESTIMATED DAY |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| **DATA** | **ID** | **VALUE** | **DSC** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | 123 | 10 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-02-31 | 123 | 20 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-03-31 | 999 | 30 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-04-31 | 999 | 40 | CLOSED MONTH |
| 2022-03-20 | 123 | 90 | ESTIMATED DAY -Because closed month 3 has different ID |
| 2022-03-25 | 123 | 100 | ESTIMATED DAY -Because closed month 3 has different ID |
| 2022-05-02 | 999 | 150 | ESTIMATED DAY -Because there is no closed month 5 |
| 2022-05-03 | 999 | 200 | ESTIMATED DAY -Because there is no closed month 5 |

Does anyone know a solution?

I tried using window function Row_number, rank and dense_rank, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not able to understands what you want, the statement is not clear, what do you mean by "when the closed value for the month does not exist."

Comment: The 'closed value' only appears on the last day of the month, and the 'estimated day' is entered daily, every day. The 'estimated day' should only be shown until the 'closed value' appears

Comment: Why the date "2022-04-30" doesn't appear in the expected output?

Comment: Because there is the 'closed month' (2022-04-31) for month 4

Answer (score 0):

create another column which contains the [closing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354105/find-the-end-of-the-month-of-a-pandas-dataframe-series) in both df1 and df2.

You can use the [isIn function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition) to filter out df2 lines based on df1[df1[closing_date, ID]]

Then, simply concat your 2 tables

Comment: I created a YEAR-MONTH column for both.

I'm trying to like:

df2 = df2[~df2[YEAR-MONTH, ID].isin(df) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join instead of a union

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df1.join(df2, ["DATA", "ID"], "outer").select(
    "DATA",
    "ID",
    F.coalesce(df1.VALUE, df2.VALUE).alias("VALUE"),
    F.coalesce(df1.DSC, df2.DSC).alias("DSC"),
)
```

Does that produce the result that you expect?

Comment: That way doesn't work because the date is different for the dataframes

Comment: Do you mean that `df2` contains dates that aren't in `df1`? If so, that's ok -- that's why I set the join type to "outer"