# Removing items from a list by comparing with a second list, Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, list-comprehension

A small example. I have two lists with numbers, `ra` and `dec` here. I have a third list that also has some numbers, `quad` here.

**What I want to do is to remove those values of `ra` and `dec` that are in `quad`.**

```
>>> ra = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> dec = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7]
>>> quad = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> new_ra = []
>>> new_dec = []
>>> for a,b in zip(ra,dec):
        if ((a not in quad) & (b not in quad)):
            new_ra.append(a)
            new_dec.append(b)
```

So here you would expect:

```
new_ra = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

and

```
new_dec = [4,5,6,7,7,7]
```

How ever, I get:

```
new_ra = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

as expected, BUT,

```
new_dec = [6,7,7,7,7]
```

Why is this so? What is wrong with my loop?

**P.S.** I am following the same method as in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another), but my second list does not give me the proper answer.

Comment: By the way `&` is bitwise `AND`, you want to use the keyword `and` for logical `AND`

Comment: I am following the same method, but my second list does not give me what I want!!! What is wrong here??

Comment: When `b` is equal to 4 `a` is equal to `2`. You add elements to `new_ra` and `new_dec` lists only when `a` is not in `quad` _and_ `b` is not in `quad`. It means, that `4` will never be added to `new_dec`

Comment: @CoryKramer: I should say that `and` does not make a difference here and I get the same results

Comment: @Alik: So how do I achieve it if I want it for remove for both the lists?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use a simple list comprehension?

```
new_ra = [v for v in ra if v not in quad]
new_dec = [v for v in dec if v not in quad]
```

Comment: `quad` could also be converted into a set to remove any possible duplicates.