# delete list of instance from iteratively created list of instances

Tags: python, list, for-loop, instances

I have created a list of instances (with a for loop). When I try to delete single instances from this list I get an error saying they aren't in the list. I have made a simple example showing my problem:

```
class example ():
    list = []

    def __init__ (self, name):
        example.list.append(self)
        self.name = name

for i in range(5):
    name = ("example_" + str(i+1))
    name = example(name)

to_delete = []

to_delete.append(example.list[2])
to_delete.append(example.list[0])
to_delete.append(example.list[4])

for j in to_delete:
    example.list.remove(to_delete)

print(example.list)
```

The objects to delete are in the list. At least, when I print them out:

```
List of instances:
[<__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082c50>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082be0>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082c88>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082b00>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082b38>]

Objects to remove:
[<__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082c88>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082c50>, <__main__.example object at 0x7fdc77082b38>]
```

Why is this behaving oddly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to remove the whole list `to_delete` from the list, not each item individually. As the object `to_delete` itself is not in the list (though each item it contains is), it will throw an error.

This:

```
for j in to_delete:
    example.list.remove(to_delete) #try to remove object to_delete
```

Should be:

```
for j in to_delete:
    example.list.remove(j) #try to remove each object IN to_delete
```

Additionally, you could simply use [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another) to do this:

```
example.list = [x for x in example.list if x not in to_delete]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this simple way of remove your to_delete sublist from the example.list

`map(example.list.remove, to_delete)`