# Python - del element in list based on another list

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list2 = [10,11,12,13,5,7]
```

and now i want that list2 should be cutted for same elements in list1 and list2

--> `list2 = [10, 11, 12, 13]`
5 and 7 is deleted because they are also in list1.

this is what i  tried:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    test = list1[i]
    if test in list2:
        del list2[list1[i]]
print(list2)
```

but list2 is the same as before :-(

hope you can help me
EDIT: Sorry i forgot to say that the lists have got dates in datetime type. does it still work ?

Comment: just create a new list `new = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]`

Comment: merge two list and use list(set(list_name)) to remove duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, first cast both `list` to `set` , now easily you can find differnce between two `set` then cast result to `list` and assign that to `list2`:

```
list2 = list(set(list2)-set(list1))

list2 # [10, 11, 12, 13]
```

However this works only when you dont have duplicates in lists.

Comment: It will remove duplicate items of list

Comment: @AlokThakur , you mean same items in one list?

Comment: If I have list2 = [10,11,12,13,5,7,10,11,12] and list1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] then result shouldn't be [10, 11, 12, 13]

Comment: @AlokThakur , yeah you right , this works only for not duplicate in lists

Answer (score 2):

You can do some easy ways:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> list2 = [10,11,12,13,5,7]
>>> [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]
[10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Or, you can use `filter`,

```
>>> filter(lambda item: item not in list1, list2)
[10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Or you can use `generator function` like this,

```
>>> def diff_list(lst1, lst2):
...     for item in lst1:
...         if item not in lst2:
...            yield item
... 
>>> list(diff_list(list2, list1))
[10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deletion is wrong, you are deleting the element in `list2` on index `list1[i]` instead of deleting `list2[index_in_list2]` or using `remove` like this `list2.remove(list1[i])`

```
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        list2.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list2 = [10,11,12,13,5,7]

list2 = [i for i in list2 if not i in list1]
print list2
```