# python set type not sorted

Tags: python, sorting

I have a very odd issue when trying to sort my permutations.

As I have seen before on SO, using a set to sort and distinct a list is the way to go, but for one particular list, this seems not to work. We can take this for example

```
>>> set([2,1])
{1, 2}
>>> set([1,2,1])
{1, 2}
>>> set([513, 135, 531, 153, 315, 351])
{513, 135, 531, 153, 315, 351}
>>>
```

Anyone who can give me any guidance?

Comment: sets are unordered

Comment: I don't know what post you saw here that said that the `set` type is a way to put things in order, but it's wrong.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another#comment72447399_4211265

Comment: @RASG - Sets put things in _an_ order... an arbitrary order, varying by implementation. The implementer could choose the same order `sorted()` uses, or the reverse of that, or add randomization, or anything they want. This question is about why a particular implementation doesn't iterate over a set in the same order that `sorted()` would, and the answer is that whoever wrote it didn't want it to. This is why Python sets are considered unsorted.

Answer (score 3):

Sets are by definition an unordered collection.

To get a sorted collection from a set use

`sorted(set([2,1]))`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html