# python remove elements of list from another list WITH MULTIPLE OCCURRENCES of items in both

Tags: python, list

Related to: [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

I have listA `[1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7]` and listB `[1, 2, 5, 5, 7]` and I want to subtract *occurrences* of items from listA. The result should be a new list: `[1, 3, 5]`
Note:

1. `1` had 2 occurrences in listA and once in listB, now it appears 2-1=1 times
2. `2` did not appear in listA, so nothing happens
3. `3` stays with 1 occurrence, as its not in listB
4. `5` occurred 3 times in listA and 2 in listB, so now it occurs 3-2=1 times
5. `7` occurred once in listA and once in listB, so now it will appear 1-1=0 times

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non list comprehension version for those new to Python

```
listA = [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7]
listB = [1, 2, 5, 5, 7]
for i in listB:
    if i in listA:
        listA.remove(i)

print listA
```

Answer (score 3):

In cases like these a list comprehension should always be used:

```
listA = [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7]
listB = [1, 2, 5, 5, 7]

newList = [i for i in listA if i not in listB or listB.remove(i)]

print (newList)
```

Here are the results:

`[1, 3, 5]`

Comment: Side effects aren't generally used with list comprehensions.  The @Dart answer is more straightforward and doesn't have the possibly undesired side effect of modifying `listB`.  The OP only wanted items removed from `listA`.  This didn't remove items from `listA`, but generated a new list.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Great remark. If the OP specified what he/she wanted as the output, I can attune my answer to that.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what I meant. @see-dart solution's is straight-forward, but I was looking for this kind of one-liner

Comment: brilliant and fast - couldn't find anything like this answer elsewhere