# How to remove specific set of list from a list?

Tags: python

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]   
b = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to remove the `[0, 0, 0, 0]` from list a.
How do I do this?

Comment: Are the elements to be removed or the list that fits (in exact order)? Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another

Comment: the list that fits in exact order needs to be removed

Comment: Is it indeed a list of 0s and 1s?

Comment: yes it is! it is a list of 0s and 1s

Comment: Is there more than one instance of `b` in `a`?

Comment: no, there's only one instance of b in a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python remove elements of list from another list WITH MULTIPLE OCCURRENCES of items in both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544296/python-remove-elements-of-list-from-another-list-with-multiple-occurrences-of-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert each list to a string:

```
a1 = ''.join('1' if x else '0' for x in a)
b1 = ''.join('1' if x else '0' for x in b)
```

Find the start index of `b1` in `a1`:

```
start = a1.index(b1)
```

The end index is `start` index plus the length of `b1`:

```
end = start + len(b1)
```

Now, extract the original list fragments before `start` and after `end` and combine them:

```
newlist = a[:start] + a[end:]
```

Comment: Note that I incorrectly used `start+end` instead of `end` in the last line, and it worked because `start==0`. The answer is now fixed.