# Python list filter performance

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to do

```
In [21]: l1 = range(1,1000000)

In [22]: l2 = range(100,90000)

In [23]: l1.append(101)

In [24]: print(set([x for x in l1 if l1.count(x) - l2.count(x) == 1]))
```

in my python shell this takes ages. Generally my goal is to substract a list from a second one while taking care of duplicates.

e.g

```
[1,2,2,3] - [2,3] = [1,2]
```

I'd be very glad for any hint how to get this done in max 500ms on a regular single core machine.

Comment: Do you care about element ordering in the result list?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another

Comment: Do you only want to keep elements that appear exactly once more in l1 than in l2? And if it does, keep that element for each occurence in l1?

Comment: @soon: nope I don't

Comment: @Moberg anser is somehow yes. but my number logic is that an element cannot occur more then one more time it does in l2.

Comment: @patroqueeet would `[1,2,2,2,3]` also be `[1,2]` or `[1, 2, 2]` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements, the number occurence in my case represents ownership (l1 = bought, l2 = sold). means a number can only occur equally counted on both lists (sold state) or one more time in l1 then in l2 (owning state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the merge pattern is even faster (read http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/list_algorithms.html#alice-in-wonderland-again):

```
  6 def substract_list(origin, substract):
  7     """
  8     example: db tells us that user bought shares 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 and also sold
  9     1, 2, 2. we need to know that he now owns 3, 4 for 10m item
 10
 11     learned from here:
 12     http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/list_algorithms.html#alice-in-wonderland-again
 13
 14     lists need to be sorted and can contain duplicates
 15     """
 16     result = []
 17     xi = 0  # @origin
 18     yi = 0  # @subscract
 19
 20     len_substract = len(substract)
 21     len_origin = len(origin)
 22
 23     while True:
 24         # reached end of substract, append rest of origin, return
 25         if yi >= len_substract:
 26             result.extend(origin[xi:])
 27             return result
 28
 29         # reached end of origin, return
 30         if xi >= len_origin:
 31             return result
 32
 33         # step throught the values
 34         if origin[xi] == substract[yi]:
 35             # equal values, next one pls
 36             yi += 1
 37             xi += 1
 38         elif origin[xi] > substract[yi]:
 39             yi += 1
 40         else:
 41             result.append(origin[xi])
 42             xi += 1
```

Counter did on my machine: 3-4s, merge pattern: 0.3s

Answer (score 5):

**Non order preserving** using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter([1, 2, 2, 3])
b = Counter([2, 3])
res = list(a - b )
# [1, 2]
```

This works because the `-` method of a `Counter` removes any elements from the output where the count present in `b` is equal to or greater than the count in `a`.

**Order preserving** using an `OrderedCounter`, then manually generate the list, eg:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

a = OrderedCounter([3, 2, 2, 1])
b = Counter([2, 3])
res = [k for k, v in a.items() if v - b[k] > 0]
# [2, 1]
```

Finally, if the original range contains non-unique values, and you want the elements duplicated the number of times that are left over after the subtraction, then:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

a = OrderedCounter([3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1])
b = Counter([2, 3])
res = [k for k, v in a.items() for _ in range(v - b[k])]
# [3, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: I don't care about order. so I validated your first approach and git 1.6s rendering time on 2015 macbook pro. thx for the fast and perfect help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I would use `Counter`, then convert the result of subtracting the two counters to a sorted list:

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
l2 = [2, 3]

counter_l1 = Counter(l1)
counter_l2 = Counter(l2)

res = counter_l1 - counter_l2

print(sorted(res))
>> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the elements first:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count1 = defaultdict(int)
count2 = defaultdict(int)

for x in l1:
    count1[x] += 1
for x in l2:
    count2[x] += 1

print([x for x, count in count1.iteritems() if count - count2[x] == 1])
```

(don't forget to convert `l1` to a set in the last line)

The above code takes 625ms on my machine. (without printing results to stdout)

Comment: Be careful: elements may appear multiple times in l1. Alternatively, we could iterate on count1 keys. Actually, this is a better idea, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: After you've got `count1` and `count2` you no longer need to worry about the original lists...

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The original list is only useful for preserving order.

Answer (score 0):

execute time:

```
import time
from functools import wraps
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):pass

def tefn(fn):
    t = time.time()
    set(fn())
    return t - time.time()

def efn(fn):
    t = time.time()
    fn()
    return t - time.time()

def runTime(tp=0, count=10):
    def dec(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrap():
            print(fn)
            res = tefn if tp else efn
            return sum(res(fn) for _ in range(count)) / count
        return wrap
    return dec


@runTime(tp=1)
def fnList():
    return [x for x in l1 if l1.count(x) - l2.count(x) == 1]
@runTime(tp=1)
def fnIter():
    return iter(x for x in l1 if l1.count(x) - l2.count(x) == 1)
@runTime(tp=1)
def fnYield():
    for x in l1:
        if l1.count(x) - l2.count(x) == 1:
            yield x
@runTime()
def fnCounter():
    a = Counter(l1)
    b = Counter(l2)
    return list(a - b )
@runTime()
def fnOrderedCounter():
    a = OrderedCounter(l1)
    b = Counter(l2)
    return [k for k, v in a.items() if v - b[k] > 0]
@runTime()
def fnDefaultdict():
    count1 = defaultdict(int)
    count2 = defaultdict(int)
    for x in l1: count1[x] += 1
    for x in l2: count2[x] += 1
    return [x for x, count in count1.items() if count - count2[x] == 1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = range(1, 1000000)
    l2 = range(100, 90000)
    g = globals()

    result = list((fn.__name__, fn()) for fn in (g[f] for f in g if f.startswith('fn')))
    result.sort(key=lambda r: r[1], reverse=True)
    for e, r in enumerate(result):
        print(e, r)
```

OUT:

```
<function fnList at 0x02F17540>
<function fnIter at 0x034C8DF8>
<function fnCounter at 0x034C8F18>
<function fnDefaultdict at 0x034CB078>
<function fnYield at 0x034C8E88>
<function fnOrderedCounter at 0x034C8FA8>
0 ('fnYield', -0.8542306900024415)
1 ('fnList', -0.8605266094207764)
2 ('fnIter', -0.8655695915222168)
3 ('fnDefaultdict', -1.054802918434143)
4 ('fnCounter', -1.3413111925125123)
5 ('fnOrderedCounter', -5.433168196678162)
```

Comment: dear, I'm not sure about your code. mind adding some words explaining your approach and your outcome?