# Strip outer elements from list that are contained in another list

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove all outer elements of a list that are contained in a second list, while keeping ones that may be 'sandwiched' inside. I know how to take the complement of the intersection of two sets, but here I just want to remove all beginning and trailing elements. So far I've come up with the following, but it feels clunky:

```
def strip_list(l, to_remove):
    while l[0] in to_remove:
        l.pop(0)
    while l and l[-1] in to_remove:
        l.pop(-1)
    return l

mylist = ['one', 'two', 'yellow', 'one', 'blue', 'three', 'four']
nums = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
strip_list(mylist, nums)
# > ['yellow', 'one', 'blue']
```

Comment: `set(my_list) - set(nums)`?

Comment: @sytech that would removed also duplicates that should be left

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Comment: @damores It's not a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def strip_list(data, to_remove):  
    idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(data) if v not in to_remove]  
    return data[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1]
```

Comment: lol, i am working on exactly same piece of code, this will fail if all items from input list match inside to_remove list

Comment: change the return to return data[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1] if idx else [] , then shall be perfect