# Pythonic way subtract list left duplicate elements

Tags: python, list

I want to subtract two lists and read this question [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

```
# a-b
def subb(a,b):
    return [i for i in a if i not in b]

print subb([1,2,1,2],[1,2])
```

But the result is empty list which is not what I want,I think it should be `[1,2]`,so I change my code,:

```
def subb(a,b):
    for i in b:
        if i in a:
            a.remove(i)
    return a
```

Now I want a Pythonic way to replace this function with a simple expression so that I can use the result in function easily.Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: So the problem is that `subb` is destructive?

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning,this is what you want:

```
x, y = [1,2,1,2], [1,2]

print [j for j in x if not j in y or y.remove(j)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

If you want the value of `y` to remain the same,you can try to use `deepcopy`,

```
from copy import deepcopy
yy = deepcopy(y)
print [j for j in x if not j in yy or yy.remove(j)]
```

Comment: This is pretty way!

Comment: But this works destructive on `y` @Mike

Comment: Yeah,only I need is the result.