# Removing elements from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with this shape:

```
temp5=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
   temp5.append(df['text'][i].split())
df['each']=temp5
df['each']
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

now I want to remove some elements of the previous list. I want to check if each word of the previous list is similar to the following list, remove it from it. the second list is like this:

```
stopwords = open('stop_words.txt','r').read().split('\n')
print(stopwords)
```

[image]

now I wrote this code to delete the same words of each list from the first one. but all I receive is NONE.
Could you please help me with it?

```
for k in range(0,len(df)):
    for j in df['each'][k][:]:
        for f in stopwords:
            if f==j:
                temp6.append(df['each'][k][:].remove(f))
                print(temp6)
```

Comment: Just ``my_list.remove(x)``. This works in-place i.e. it modifies the list it is called on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `remove` method removes inplace, but if you want something more 'pythonic', the working code would be

```
temp5=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    temp5.append([x for x in df['text'][i].split() if x not in stopwords])
```

using the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as mentioned e.g. [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another), which creates the filtered list. Or, if you insist on using the original dataframe as input, it would be something like

```
temp5=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    temp5.append([x for x in df['each'][i] if x not in stopwords])
```