# Deleting all files and directories except a few specified in a "list" in python

Tags: python, directory, find, exec, delete-directory

Consider my root dir `ls` gives the following output:

```
1  2  3  4  a  b  c  d
```

Some files and some dirs.
I want to remove all except a few.
I can do :

```
out = subprocess.check_output(['['find', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '!', '-iname', 'a', '!' '-iname', 'b', '!' '-iname', 'c', '!' , '-iname', 'd', '-exec',  'rm', '-rf',  '{}' , '+'])
```

But I want to specify all *not to delete dirs and files* in a list instead of making the command so long, and tough to read,
ie, something like:

```
goodfilesList = ['a', 'b','c', 'd']
out = subprocess.check_output(['find', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '!', '-iname'] + goodfilesList)
```

Comment: you can try `set([1,2,6,8]) - set([2,3,5,8])`. This gives `set([1, 6])` https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211239/2861108

Answer (score 0):

You can try list compression to create the command you want.

something like:

```
flist = ['a','b','c']

command = ['find', '.', '-maxdepth', '1']
[command.extend(['!','-iname',fname]) for fname in flist] # command ==  ['find', '.', '-maxdepth', '1', '!', '-iname', 'a', '!', '-iname', 'b', '!', '-iname', 'c']
command.extend(['-exec',  'rm', '-rf',  '{}' , '+'])

out = subprocess.check_output(command)
```