# Substracting string list with another string list

Tags: python

I'm remaking this post to be more clear about my problem

Comment: this ==> [i for i in A if i not in B].

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but this solution doesn't work for me, I just don't see why

Comment: Whitespace around your strings. Use `.strip()` on them. Or add a reliable example of your data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) to create a new list. With the following code you're checking whether an element `x` from `A` is in `B`. Every time `x` is in `B`, it is not included in your new list `C`.

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
B = [1, 3, 4]

C = [x for x in A if x not in B]
print(C)
```

outputs:

```
[2, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: This soution doesn't work for me. In reality, A has 545332 string elements and B has 23. When running C = [x for x in A if x not in B], C elements are the same as B, substraction didn't happen