# Python: Remove string that occurs in one list from another for every row

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have two lists per account id (table below). I want to remove any elements that appear in list 1 (competitor_old) that also appear in list 2 (competitor_new). Essential `L2 - L1` per row.

So from the table below I would have a new column (competitor_new_unique) and for the first row the a value would be c,d

table

```
      account_id competitor_old competitor_new 
          234241            a,b        a,b,c,d
           53266              h            h,s
          342536              j              j
          325632              s          s,g,e
          324346              f              f
```

desired result

```
 account_id competitor_old competitor_new competitor_new_unique
      234241            a,b        a,b,c,d                   c,d
       53266              h            h,s                     s
      342536              j              j
      325632              s          s,g,e                   g,e
      324346              f              f
```

Most of my efforts can be derived from another post. [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are they lists or sets? I mean, are the values unique within the lists? Also, does order matter?

Comment: Input is in which form of data structure? How is the table stored?

Comment: "Most of my efforts can be derived from another post..." Can you show us your latest attempt?

Comment: It seems you are looking for `set` operations. Try something like `set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) - set(['a', 'b'])`.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco - The values are unique within the lists. The order does not matter.

I am getting my table from a CSV file

I have tried using set but I get the resulting erreor TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

As for my attempts 

`so = data.competitor_old   
sn = data.competitor_new    
s1 =  [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in so]
s2 = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in sn]`

Attempts

`sf = [x for x in sn1 if x not in so1]`

`lambda x: x not in s1, s2`

`set(sn1) - set(so1)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
for id in account_id:
    id["competitor_new_unique"] = [x for x in id["competitor_new"] if x not in id["competitor_old"]]
```