# How To Remove an Element from a List Using Another List's Placeholder in Python

Tags: python, list

I need to remove a certain element from a list of dictionaries. Unfortunately, the only reference to the object needing removal is a place in another list:

```
enemy_list[num]
```

I need to take out `enemy_list[num]` from `everyone`.

```
ii = 0
for i in enemy_list:
  print(ii, ':', enemy_list[ii])
  ii += 1
num = input("Which of your opponents would you like to eliminate? ")
num = int(num)
del everyone[enemy_list[num]]
```

I cannot remove it from only `enemy_list` because it is reset multiple times as everyone in list `everyone` takes a turn.
[I tried this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another), but it only worked from removing entire lists from eachother. Is there a way I could change it to work for this case?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You only want to remove a certain element. Why not just use `list.remove`?

Comment: It doesn't work, because I don't know what said element is, aside from its place inside list1.

Comment: `list2.remove(list1[index])`?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: What are they lists of? objects? do they hold the same reference? It would really help to create a [mcve].

Comment: I said at the top they are lists of dictionaries.

Comment: Based on what you have described, `remove` should work. Proof: https://repl.it/repls/SizzlingWorthwhileShell

Comment: Great, so do they hold the same reference?

Comment: Yeah, I misinterpreted where the error was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
everyone.remove(enemy_list[num])
```

Comment: OP has already stated that it doesn't work

Comment: This actually does work, I was calling the wrong function inside my code. XD