# Deleting all values from list a if they are present in list b

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
def array_diff(a, b):

result = []
i = 0;
j = 0;

if (a[i] == b[j]):
        a = a.remove(a[i]) #append() method in python adds a single item to the existing list
        
        if i<len(a):
            i+=1;
        return a;
        if j<len(b):
            i+=1;
        return a;
```

It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b. If I should give an example:

```
array_diff([1,2],[1]) == [2] 
array_diff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]
```

I am very new to Python language, so I would appreciate any help. What am I doing wrong and how can I make it better?

I edited:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    b=set(b)
    for v in a:
        if v in b:
           a.remove(v)
    return list(a)
```

However, when a was [1,2,2], b was [2], expected [1]: it returns [1, 2] while it should equal [1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Answer (score 0):

```
def diff(lst,lst2):
    lst=set(lst)
    for v in lst2:
        if v in lst:
           lst.remove(v)
    return list(lst)
print(diff([1,2,3],[3,5,7,8]))
```

Comment: Assume we do not know what is inside of the arrays. And I am getting "name 'v' is not defined" error. Why might it be? Thank you so much.

Comment: edit: it does not remove duplicates, not defined error is solved

Comment: It's executable code... please try again..if you are not able to get solution...attach snap i will see

Comment: I have edited the code try now

Comment: Yes no problem now except duplicates.How can I remove multiple same variables?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple same variable?

Comment: assume a was [1,2,2], b was [1], expected [2,2]: it returns [2] but should equal [2, 2]. or assume a was [1,2,2], b was [ ], expected [1,2,2]: it returns [1, 2] but should equal [1, 2, 2] :( I am checking the books now too.

Comment: Read your question again as you said...array_diff([1,2],[1]) == [2] 
array_diff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]...ans is working same