# How to remove all items in a list that are in another list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I'm trying to write a function that takes as input two lists: `def array_diff(a, b):`. In this function, I would like to return a filtered `a` list that will have been removed all items that are also present in list `b`. It will work as such:

`array_diff([1,2],[1]) == [2]`

Or:

`array_diff([1,2,2,2,3],[2]) == [1,3]`

I have written the following code:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            a.remove(i)      
    return a
```

But even though I get no errors, when I try to run this function and list `a` has two items with the same value, and it is present in list `b`, it doesn't filter it properly. I'm not sure why this is happening, but I already tried using `a.pop(i)` as well, but also didn't work. I also tried iterating over the list with `for i in range(len(a))`, but I get errors saying I went over the list's index.

Hopefully, you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Don't remove elements while iterating over it.

Comment: `it doesn't filter it properly`. please explain, give a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)

Comment: [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s may make this significantly easier.

Comment: @AAAlex123 here: `a was [1,2,2], b was [2], expected [1]: [1, 2] should equal [1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to create a new list with all the items of `a` that are not in `b` like this:

```py
def array_diff(a, b):
    return [item for item in a if item not in b]

ls1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls2 = [2, 5]

print(array_diff(ls1, ls2))  # should be [1, 3, 4]
print(array_diff(ls2, ls1))  # should be []
```

Alternatively, you can use the `filter` function to filter out any item in `a` that is also in `b`.

```py
def array_diff(a, b):    
    return list(filter(lambda item: item not in b, a))

ls1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls2 = [2, 5]

print(array_diff(ls1, ls2))  # should be [1, 3, 4]
print(array_diff(ls2, ls1))  # should be []
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler approach
eg.

```
a = [1,2,2,2,2,3]
b = [2]
c = list(set(a)-set(b)) # for output in list
print(c)
```

Comment: This would remove duplicates from list a that are not in list b as well

Comment: Oh yeah, i didnt consider that, I'll edit it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only unique values then:

```
def array_diff(a, b):     
    return set(a) - set(b)
```

Comment: Hey! This didn't work...

Comment: @JohnRayburn "didn't work" is suuuuuch a useful description of how it didn't work.

Comment: @superbrain, this didn't give out any errors but all of the outputs were wrong.

Comment: @JohnRayburn what do you mean "didn't work"?

Comment: @busfighter I answered this in the previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRayburn "were wrong" is suuuuuch a useful description of how they were wrong.

Comment: @JohnRayburn can you provide an example of wrong behaviour?

Comment: Hey @busfighter, AAAlex123's answered worked. Thank you for your support!

Comment: It also works but faster because set operations are faster in python) I think you can't provide an example because you pass the result into some checking system and actually dont' have those examples. Checking system doesn't take the result because it's of type `set` not `list` but the result made by my solution is right.