# Python remove elements from a list that contains substrings from other list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, and I want to remove the elements on a list `l1` that have any different substring not mentioned in `l2`. My lists are the following:

```
l1 = ['PC||macOS||Xbox One||PlayStation 4||Nintendo Switch',
 'macOS||PC||Xbox One',
 'iOS',
 'PC||PlayStation 4',
 'PC',
 'Web',
 'PC||macOS',
 'PC||macOS||Linux',
 'PC||Linux',
 'PC||Web',
 'PC||Xbox One||PlayStation 4||Nintendo Switch',
 'PC||macOS||Linux||Web',
 'macOS||PC||Linux||PlayStation 4||Xbox One',
 'PC||Android',
 'PC||macOS||Linux||Android',
 'macOS||iOS||Linux||PC||PlayStation 4',
 'Linux',
 'PC||macOS||Web',
 nan,
 'Xbox One||PC||Nintendo Switch||PlayStation 4',
 'iOS||PC||macOS||Linux',
 'PC||macOS||Android||Web',
 'iOS||Linux||PC||macOS',
 'Android',
 'macOS||PC||Linux',
 'Linux||PC'
]

l2 = ['PC', 'macOS', 'Linux', 'mac', 'Web']
```

What I want to obtain is all combinations in `l1` that ONLY have the substrings stated in `l2`. Therefore, in the new list I won't have any element with words like "Playstation 4" or "iOS" or "Xbox One". Something like:

```
l3 = [
 'PC',
 'Web',
 'PC||macOS',
 'PC||macOS||Linux',
 'PC||Linux',
 'PC||Web',
 'PC||macOS||Linux||Web',
 'PC||macOS||Linux||Android',
 'Linux',
 'PC||macOS||Web',
 'macOS||PC||Linux',
 'Linux||PC'
]
```

Comment: what have you done so far? also may I ask if you are familiar with regular expressions? cause I think it will do the job :D

Comment: I've tried with nested for loops and 'str.contains()' and adapting this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another but with no result

Comment: Loop over the items in list1.  For each item, split it on `||` and do a nested loop on the split items, comparing each one to the items in list2.  If you get to the end of the nested loop without finding any matches, append the item to list3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `l2` a set for fast lookup then use `all` with a generator comprehension:

```py
l2_set = set(l2)
l3 = [x for x in l1 if all(chunk in l2_set for chunk in x.split("||"))]
```

Comment: pretty much I was also targeting for, a bit of explanation might help with the cryptic code.

Answer (score 3):

using sets is pretty easy.

```
l3 = [v for v in l1 if set(v.split('||')) <= set(l2)]
```

gonna have to filter out that errant nan though...

Comment: This one also works perfectly, but Aplet123 answered before, so I chose his answer as the final one. Thanks a lot @acushner

Comment: no offense here, glad you got some good answers!