# Trouble with removing list elements that are present in another list

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio

I am attempting to add items to a new list from a primary list, then remove those moved items from the primary list. Essentially use and discard.

I have already attempted to use list comprehensions ([Remove all the elements that occur in one list from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another)).
Then I attempted to use a for loop as well as an if statement to check for the elements and remove them, though when I printed the original list once again, nothing changed.

Not sure what I am doing wrong but it is extremely frustrating:

```
your_hand_list = []
computer_hand_list = []
computer_hand_list.append (random.sample(card_list, 5))
your_hand_list.append (random.sample(card_list, 5))

print (your_hand_list, computer_hand_list)

for card in your_hand_list and computer_hand_list:
    if card in card_list:
        card_list.remove(card)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the [tour] and read [ask]. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Adding your code made it much easier to understand your issue.  Specifically, the problem is this statement:

```
for card in your_hand_list and computer_hand_list:
```

The Python `and` operator does not work the way you were expecting it to in this context.  Instead, the Python standard itertools library has a function called `chain` that will solve your problem.  Here is a (greatly) simplified version of your code for illustration purposes.

Example:

```
from itertools import chain

card_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
your_hand_list = [1, 4, 7]
computer_hand_list = [3, 9, 10]

for card in chain(your_hand_list, computer_hand_list):
    if card in card_list:
        card_list.remove(card)

print(card_list)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I edited my post with a picture of the code, sorry for not doing that before, new to the whole python and stackoverflow thing. For clarification, I am making a Crazy Eighths type of game so I need to to remove the "card" that is given to the player from the original list of cards in order to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I wasn't given an error when executing the code, telling me it seemingly worked, but again, the original card_list was not changed at all? Not sure what I am doing wrong since I used your code practically. I am using Visual Studio Code for macOS, I even tried it in Pycharm in case it was the program.